# Powershells write-verbose creates no outputvariable (-ov)

Tags: debugging, powershell

Not critical but gave me a headache...
I wanted the output of write-verbose into a variable for documentation/debugging.
Its nice, powershel has an own parameter for the output of commands (see help about_commonparameters).
But whats not stated in the help is: what write-* output goes to what variable
so i tried and tried and found out:

- `write-warning` writes just to **-warningVariable**
- `write-error` writes just to **-errorVariable**
- `write-output` writes just to **-outVariable**

BUT  where goes the `write-verbose` output?
The help says

> This cmdlet supports the common parameters: -Verbose, -Debug, -ErrorAction, -ErrorVariable, -OutBuffer, and -OutVariable.

For Example:
`write-verbose "test" -verbose -outvariable $a`
Nothings in $a

(same for `write-warning "test" -ev $b`... nothing)
any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'continue'
Write-Verbose ($a = 'foo')
$a

VERBOSE: foo
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Write-Verbose has no "output" to write to an OutVariable.  It does write things to the verbose stream, though.

OutVariable contains all objects that were output to the output stream.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. anyway, thats confusing - why there is the outvariable parameter when there is nothing written to the output stream. So there is no option to capture the verbose output? Like "show me what you do and at the same time write it to the log-file"

Comment: There is no "granular" availability for the common parameters.  Either you have all of them or you don't.  You can use redirection to get the verbose output merged with the output stream or send it to a file if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the output of `Write-Verbose` in a variable you could use [redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx):

```
$var = Write-Verbose 'something' 4>&1
```

That will merge the verbose stream with the success output stream, which can be captured in a variable.

This won't work if you need regular and verbose output in separate variables, though. As far as I'm aware you must redirect verbose output to a file and read the file into a variable for that.

```
PS C:\> function Foo { Write-Verbose 'foo'; Write-Output 'bar' }
PS C:\> $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
PS C:\> Foo
VERBOSE: foo
bar
PS C:\> $o = Foo 4>'C:\temp\verbose.txt'
PS C:\> $v = Get-Content 'C:\temp\verbose.txt'
PS C:\> $o
bar
PS C:\> $v
foo
```

Same goes for warnings, only that warnings go to stream number 3.

```
PS C:\> function Bar { Write-Warning 'foo'; Write-Output 'bar' }
PS C:\> $WarningPreference = 'Continue'
PS C:\> Bar
WARNING: foo
bar
PS C:\> $o = Bar 3>'C:\temp\warning.txt'
PS C:\> $w = Get-Content 'C:\temp\warning.txt'
PS C:\> $o
bar
PS C:\> $w
foo
```

Redirection of the warning, verbose, and debug streams was introduced with PowerShell version 3.

Comment: thats very interesting, i didnt know about_redirection in powershell (with 3 .. 5 ), thanks for the explanation and link to the help